# firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword creates the user but it neither executes then nor catch block

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I can see that it creates the users when I check the users in firebase console, but it doesn't execute anything after that line. And it also doesn't change the auth state. I tried with them-catch, try-catch, I even tried to execute something with finally but it doesn't execute that either.

```
try {
      const authUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        signupData.email,
        signupData.password
      );
        updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: signupData.name,
        })
          .then(() => {
             addDoc(collection(db, 'users'), {
                userId: authUser.user.uid,
              });
              dispatch(setUser(authUser.user));
              setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
       }
setLoading(false) // This is not executed either.
```

I should add that it executes the catch block when there is a duplicated email or weak password error returned. But it doesn't execute the then block even after it creates the user